# plugin is not working in Webpack with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, plugins

I am creating a React JS app. I have installed terser-webpack-plugin to both try to compress my code as well as remove console.log() statements. However, it does not seem to be working.

I have installed the terser-webpack-plugin as follows:

```
npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

My webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            plugins: [
                "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: {
                        extractComments: 'all',
                        compress: {
                                drop_console: true
                        },

                }
        })
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new CopyPlugin([
      { from: 'src/css', to: 'css' }
    ])
  ]
};
```

However, when I run `npm run build` or `npm run dev` it does not seem to have any effect on the final file size and the comments are still there. What am I doing wrong?

As a side note, I am wondering how to make sure this only works for build and does not remove the comments on dev.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I discovered that the line `devtool: 'eval-source-map',` was preventing `TerserPlugin` from working. So, I have eliminated it from production. I have used winwiz1's example and modified it to fit my situation.

Something to note is that my `package.json` was using the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

So, rather than using my own environment variables I am using the mode parameter.

To use environment variables or parameters in webpack you need to modify it so that it is a function. See changes marked with comments below:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

//this was made as a function that returns a value
module.exports = (env, argv) => {

  //Here a constant isProduction is created that we can use as a switch to target code that should run either only in production or only in development mode.
  const isProduction = (argv.mode === "production")

  //Here is the return statement that returns the entire settings section as an object
  return {
    module: {
      rules: [
          // code removed for brevity  
      ]
    },
    //Will only run in production mode. Note the ... is the spread operator.
    ...(isProduction && {
      optimization: {
         //I removed the `minimize: true,` line as per winwiz1's suggestion
         minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: {
                        extractComments: 'all',
                        compress: {
                                drop_console: true
                        },
                }
             })
          ],
       },
    }),
    //Here we only set the devtool to eval-source-map if we are in development mode
    devtool: !isProduction && 'eval-source-map',
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        filename: "./index.html"
      }),
      new CopyPlugin([
        { from: 'src/css', to: 'css' }
      ])
    ]
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Using

```js
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
```

tells webpack to create and use an instance of TerserPlugin with some default configuration options. Then you create another instance of the plugin:

```js
new TerserPlugin({
```

It is better not to use `minimize: true,`

This configuration works:

```js
...(isProduction && {
        minimizer: [
          new TerserPlugin({
            cache: false,
            parallel: true,
            sourceMap: false,     // set to true if debugging of production build needed
            terserOptions: {
              keep_classnames: false,
              mangle: true,
              compress: false,
              keep_fnames: false,
              output: {
                comments: false,
              }
            }
          })
        ]
      }),
```

> I am wondering how to make sure this only works for build and does not remove the comments on dev.

Note how the boolean flag `isProduction` is used in the above code snippet. The flag is defined as follows:

```js
const isProduction = (env && env.prod) ? true : false;
```

To make the flag work you call webpack as `webpack` in dev and `webpack --env.prod` for production build.

For the reference, the above code snippet is taken from [here](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/client/webpack.config.js)

Comment: I have tracked down the issue to be the line `devtool: 'eval-source-map'` which seems to have been preventing the TerserPlugin from having any effect. I have implemented some of your suggestions in my final code as you can see in the answer I posted above.

Comment: One thing I was unclear on is how the `minimizer` property knows to use the TerserPlugin when we aren't naming what the name of the plugin is?

Comment: webpack [doco](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization): "optimization.minimize   boolean  Tell webpack to minimize the bundle using the TerserPlugin". I guess webpack has TerserPlugin hardcoded and ready to kick into action when this boolean flag is set to 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

You probably check your build file's extension!
I'm struggling with this problem and solved it by adding test regex property to .js ([default is .mjs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/))

```js
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i, // you should add this property
        terserOptions: {
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            drop_debugger: true,
            pure_funcs: ['console.log', 'console.info'], // Delete console
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
```